# AttributeError: 'IntegrityError' object has no attribute 'message' SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, error-handling, sqlalchemy

I was working through a book example on catching exceptions in SQLAlchemy Core using a try/except block:

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
ins = insert(users).values(
    username="cookiemon",            #This username is already in db, 
    email_address="damon@cookie.com", should throw an IntegrityError 
    phone="111-111-1111",             for violating unique constraint
    password="password"
    )
try:
    result=connection.execute(ins)
except IntegrityError as error:
    print(error.orig.message, error.params)
```

However, I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'IntegrityError' object has no attribute 'message'

This is verbatim from the book example, why can't I display the error message?

Comment: You're using python 3? Exceptions don't have the message attribute anymore, they have `args`. See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/#transition-plan

Comment: Yes I'm using python 3.5. Ok I just switched to print(error.args) and was able to print the error message. Thanks!

Comment: should add first comment as answer

Answer (score 5):

In Python3, exceptions no longer have the message attribute, they have args. See python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/#transition-plan

---

Credit  [Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557665/attributeerror-integrityerror-object-has-no-attribute-message-sqlalchemy#comment72267829_42557665).

Answer (score 1):

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.args[0]
                if len(self.args) <= 1
                else self.args)
```

Then, replace:

```
print(error.orig.message, error.params)
```

with:

```
print(error)
```

Comment: Hi there, portos and welcome. People of the future will thank you if you provide an explanation for what your code snippet does and why it is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

it's not error.orig.message make it

```
print(error.message)
```

will return this

(sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: users.gender